# Google Sheets App Script to extract Datadog incidents

Tags: google-sheets, datadog

I hope to import datadog incidents using a Google sheets app script on a daily interval.

I'm not sure if anyone has done this before and would appreciate some assistance

Thanks

Comment: this is possible using time trigger events for daily intervals in Apps Script, this will be accomplished using Datadog API. Here is a link where you can start your reading here https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/incidents/ so you can understand the behaviour of their API.